# Failing a build in Jenkins using the Quality Gate plugin

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I m trying to fail a build in my Jenkins server using the Quality Gate plugin (v2.5). In my jenkins i have installed SonarQube plugin (v2.4.4) and SonarQube Scanner v2.6.1. I have configured a SonarQube server as well v5.6
I have defined a quality gate  (for eg bugs > 10) in my server for the project which i m building using my Jenkins server. I have created a freestyle job for the same in Jenkins. What i want to achieve is the build in Jenkins should fail whenever the Quality Gate requirement is not met.
I use the "Execute SonarQube Scanner" option in my build step in Jenkins and the Quality Gate option in the post build action (with my project key). I have defined the parameters for sonar analysis in the Analysis Properties section.

Currently, when the quality gate threshold is not met the status changes to failed on the SonarQube server but the build is passed in Jenkins. During the next execution of the same job in Jenkins the build is failed by the Quality Gate. That is the build status is not changed in synchronization with the SonarQube server but in the following execution,

Can you pls let me know what m i missing here ?

Answer (score 4):

it's been a while since you posted this but maybe I can help at least with my understanding.

In SonarQube 5.6 (don't know when this changed) the build analysis is been analysed in a background task in SonarQube. So the Jenkins Build is finished after it posted the analysis to the server and the build is finished long before the background task on the SonarQube server is finished.

During or on the end of the background task in SonarQube it checks the QualityGate.

So the Jenkins plugin get's always "outdated" QualityGate status at least with SonarQube versions higher than 5.6.

It's possible to extend the Jenkins plugin and add a "wait for background task" option. Of course this would lead longer build times in Jenkins. This is already done in [this](https://github.com/arkanjoms/quality-gates-plugin) fork of the "Quality Gates Plugin".

Hope this all right :-)

[see the also the doku here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Breaking+the+CI+Build)